# Finding an algorithm to a simulation

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a single gold mine that produces gold at the rate of one gold unit every cycle of 20 hours (the 20 hours is not important). When it reaches 250 gold units, it immediately purchases another gold mine (costs 250 gold) so now it is producing two gold units every cycle.

Currently can only simulate it like this

```
int getCycles (int targetMines) {
    int cycle = 0;
    int goldMines = 1;
    int balance = 0;

    while (goldMines != targetMines) {
        cycle++;
        balance += goldMines;
        if (balance / 250 >= 1) {
            goldMines += balance / 250;
            balance = balance % 250;
        }
    }

    return cycle;
}
```

I am seeking a more elegant solution (perhaps more mathematic rather than computational?) to find the number of cycles (C) required to reach a target number of gold mines

Comment: It seems like it would be logarithmic. If every n cycles = double the gold mines, then to reach m gold mines you need n = log base 2 of m cycles, right? In this case they double every 250 cycles, so it would be something like `250 * log2 (m)` cycles.

Comment: @user1118321 Refine and post as an answer.

Comment: A small difference between the code in the question and the code in the answer is whether the income is discrete.

Comment: the income is discrete

Comment: You can convert it to a system of mutually recursive functions. Perhaps it can be simplified and solved trivially. I don't remember how to solve mutually recursive functions without generating functions... and I don't remember how to use generating functions :). Maybe math.stackexchange can help?

`M(t) = # of gold mines at time t, G(t) = # of gold units at time t, M(0) = 1, M(t) = M(t-1) + floor((G(t-1) + M(t-1)) / 250), G(0) = 0, G(t) = (G(t-1) + M(t-1)) % 250`

Answer (score 0):

It would be logarithmic. If every n cycles it doubles the gold mines, then to reach m gold mines you need `n * log base 2 of m` cycles. In this case they double every 250 cycles, so it would be 250 * log2 (m) cycles. In C that would be

```
numCycles = 250.0 * log2 (numMinesDesired);
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. He purchases the next gold-mine when his aggregate gold is 250, while your claim seems to assume it just doubles every 250 cycles (i.e. he can only buy another gold mine when a single gold mine hits 250... and they all hit 250 at the same time). For instance, he buys a second gold mine at 250 cycles, the third at 375, and the fourth at 375 + ceil(250/4)...